# Bullet points inside of a Tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx

I know some solutions are available to address this or similar problems. But I try my best and nothing comes out. I want to add the bullets points in Table cells. But instead of that I am getting all the points in horizontal line. Please check the image and latex script. I will be really thankful, if someone address this problem.

[image]

PS. :I am using overleaf

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Table}
\label{tbl:artefact}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\textbf{ID}                   & \textbf{Some points}                                                                            & \textbf{\#} \\ \hline
Info                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}  
 \begin{itemize}
     \item 1
     \item 2
     \item 3
     \item 4
     \item 5
     \item 6
 \end{itemize}
\end{tabular} & x1   \\ \hline
TEXT 2               &  SOME TEXT                                                                                     &   X2 \\ \hline
Text3                & Some text &  X3  \\ \hline
Text4                & Some text &  X4  \\ \hline
Text5                & Some text &  X5  \\ \hline                     Text6                & Some text &  X6  \\ \hline

Some values     &   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It is a table that shows XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (\textbf{P5}). \end{tabular}      &   X7 \\ \hline
Intended XXX   & A description XXXXXXX (\textbf{Px}).                                                        &  X8  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}\quad
}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists shad to be in paragraph box column types as are `p{<width>}`, ... or `X` and its derivatives defined in `tabularx` package.

With use of the `tabularx`, `enumitem` and `etoolbox` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
                 after=\end{minipage}}                   % <---
                        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Table}
\label{tbl:artefact}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXl}
    \toprule
\textbf{ID}                   
        & \textbf{Some points}
            & \textbf{\#}           \\ 
    \midrule
Info    &   \begin{itemize}
         \item 1
         \item 2
         \item 3
         \item 4
         \item 5
         \item 6
            \end{itemize}  
                    & x1        \\ 
    \midrule
TEXT 2  &  SOME TEXT
                    &   X2      \\   
Text3   & Some text &   X3      \\   
Text4   & Some text &   X4      \\   
Text5   & Some text &   X5      \\                    
Text6   & Some text &   X6      \\  
    \midrule 
Some values     
        & It is a table that shows XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (\textbf{P5}).
                    &   X7      \\ 
    \midrule
Intended XXX   
        & A description XXXXXXX (\textbf{Px}).                                                       
                    &  X8  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is useful and solved my problem :). Appreciated